# Loading external html/text file into pl/sql variable with flyway

Tags: sql, oracle, flyway

I'm changing database update scripts to be used with flyway and one of my scripts doesn't work anymore. It should load an external html file named 'my-template.html' into a PL/SQL variable to be loaded into an oracle database (11g). The sql script Looks like this:

```
DECLARE
  file_contents VARCHAR2(32767) := '@my-template.html';
BEGIN 

INSERT INTO my_table(id, key, value) VALUES (MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'my.template.key', file_contents);
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

This worked fine from command line using SQL plus but flyway can't handle the placeholder '@my-template.html'. It is written as it is into the db table.

Flyway doesn't substitute the filename placeholder with the contents of the corresponding external file called 'my-template.html' the way SQL Plus did.

Is there an easy alternative to load the external html file into my database via flyway?

Comment: Why do yo want to add it then. Remove SET SCAN OFF and then execute

Comment: If I remove SET SCAN OFF the placeholder string '@my-template.html' is not substituted with the file contents of the file 'my-template.html'.

Comment: You need to declare your file_contents as clob . Varchar2 has limit is 32k .

Comment: I see, I changed the example. Actually I do have it set to 32767.

Comment: SET SCAN is used to control whether or not it should scan for substitution params/variables. OFF would prevent scanning for params/variables. Doesnot going to impact if you OFF it or ON it until you are passing some substitution value